# Likewise open aka powerbroker open, dns error when joining domain

Tags: linux, active-directory

When joining the domain using powerbroker open on a machine which is a bind dns server, i'm running into an issue.

I'm not totally sure what powerbroker is trying to do at this point exactly (investigating that) - my assumption is it's trying to read some sort of SRV record from DNS, but because the machine is actually a bind DNS server (and resolv.conf points to 127.0.0.1) its running into trouble.

Using:

`sudo domainjoin-cli join --assumeDefaultDomain yes MYDOMAIN.LAN myuser`

i'm seeing:

`Error: DNS_ERROR_BAD_PACKET [code 0x0000251e]
A bad packet was received from a DNS server. Potentially the requested address does not exist.`

Is there a decent solution to this which allows bind to still point to localhost ? I don't think i can just use the domain dns servers in /etc/resolv.conf. I found a few people asking similar questions but this machine is a bind server itsself which seems to make the solutions provided not do-able.

Answer (score 0):

As long as DNS is returning the appropriate SRV records for the AD domain, it should work.

Another option is to try Centrify Express.  It provides a utility called adcheck that runs a set of checks, including DNS checks, to make sure the system can probably join AD.  If there's a DNS problem, adcheck should point it out to you.  If adcheck doesn't complain and you still can't join with Powerbroker, consider using Centrify Express instead.